# Adding a strut at the top/bottom of large equations

Tags: strut

I woud like to typeset a very long equation that includes two large brackets that dynamically adjust heights depending on their contents. The typical way is to use `\left[ \right]`

[image]

As you see above, the brackets seem to be short for their contents. One potential solution is to use `\bigstrut`. However, this does not work unless `\bigstrutjot` is modified to be larger than the default. This means that I must define a custom strut command as follows

```
\newlength{\heightbigstrut}
\setlength{\heightbigstrut}{3mm}
\newcommand{\bigstrutX}[2][0]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
        % No optional argument is provided
        {\renewcommand{\bigstrutjot}{\heightbigstrut} \bigstrut[#2]}
        % Optional argument provided
        {\renewcommand{\bigstrutjot}{#1} \bigstrut[#2]}
                            }
```

The result would then become

[image]

This is the result that I actually want. However, the custom code above is suboptimal because I need to manually determine the height for the top and bottom struts. Changing the contents means that I also must change the struts lengths

My question: what is some alternative method that automatically specifies the height of the big strut?

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{ifthen}

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

        \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=false}

        % Horizontal
        \geometry{inner=20mm, outer=20mm, includemp=true, bindingoffset=0mm, marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm}

        % Vertical
        \geometry{top=20mm, vmarginratio=3:5, includehead=true, includefoot=true, headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=5mm}


    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{bigstrut}

        \newlength{\heightbigstrut}
        \setlength{\heightbigstrut}{3mm}
        \newcommand{\bigstrutX}[2][0]{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
                % No optional argument is provided
                {\renewcommand{\bigstrutjot}{\heightbigstrut} \bigstrut[#2]}
                % Optional argument provided
                {\renewcommand{\bigstrutjot}{#1} \bigstrut[#2]}
                                    }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \min \left[
    \begin{aligned}
            & \sum\limits_{t \in T} \left(p_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}} P_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}} - p_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}} P_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}}\right) \Delta t
    \\
            &\left(
            \sum\limits_{t \in T} \left(P_{t}^{L} p_{P}^{L} + P_{t}^{An} p_{P}^{An} + P_{t}^{IP} p_{P}^{IP}\right) +
            E_{T}^{L} p_{E}^{L} + E_{T}^{An} p_{E}^{An} + E_{T}^{IP} p_{E}^{IP}
            \right)
    \end{aligned}
    \right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Scale the fences manually using say `\Bigl(....\Bigr)` and its `\bigg` and `\Bigg` cousins. In many situations using `\left/right` is not a good idea as it becomes too large.

Comment: the brackets in the first look better than the ones in the second, why do you want them so large? I would also use smaller () in the inner expressions. and drop the parens that surrounds the second row, which does not appear to be needed at all?

Answer (score 2):

You're right in thinking that the result is not optimal. Unfortunately, I see no real way to automate the adjustment.

In this particular case, adding a dummy superscript is sufficient.

In the following I changed all `\left` and `\right` to manually sized fences: the size chosen by `\left` and `\right` turns out to be too big.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \min \left[\;
  \begin{aligned}
    &\sum_{t \in T}^{} \bigl(
        p_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}} P_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}} - 
        p_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}} P_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}}
      \bigr) \Delta t
    \\[1ex]
    &+\Bigl(\,% <--- avoid clash with subscript
       \sum_{t \in T} \bigl(
         P_{t}^{L} p_{P}^{L} + P_{t}^{An} p_{P}^{An} + P_{t}^{IP} p_{P}^{IP}
       \bigr) +
       E_{T}^{L} p_{E}^{L} + E_{T}^{An} p_{E}^{An} + E_{T}^{IP} p_{E}^{IP}
      \Bigr)
    \end{aligned}
    \;\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Some spacing between the fence and the expressions seems better, judge for yourself.

[image]

On the other hand, I personally would use `multline`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
  \min\biggl[\,
    \sum_{t \in T}^{} \bigl(
        p_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}} P_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}} - 
        p_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}} P_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}}
      \bigr) \Delta t
    \\
    +\Bigl(\,% <--- avoid clash with subscript
       \sum_{t \in T} \bigl(
         P_{t}^{L} p_{P}^{L} + P_{t}^{An} p_{P}^{An} + P_{t}^{IP} p_{P}^{IP}
       \bigr) +
       E_{T}^{L} p_{E}^{L} + E_{T}^{An} p_{E}^{An} + E_{T}^{IP} p_{E}^{IP}
      \Bigr)\biggr]
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]